# ParseSwift queryConstraint on object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can i add a queryConstraint on a object?

This is my current code but it returns no objects. I guess my current code is actually to query on arrays and not objects. But I can't find a way to do this for objects.

```
let query = Device.query()
                .where(containsString(key: "apps", substring: "Google"))
```

This is the database

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the [playgrounds](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/tree/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages) to see how to use ParseSwift properly. More specifically, [finding objects](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/blob/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/2%20-%20Finding%20Objects.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift).

The first problem is `apps` is an object, which is actually a dictionary. You can’t use a substring constraint on a dictionary or other object. The actual way to do it is:

```swift
let objectToFind = [“Google”: “300”]
let query = Device.query("apps" == objectToFind),
```

Comment: I know it’s a dictionary, but so you are saying there is no way of actually creating a queryConstraint to search the keys of the dictionary only? Because i cant search the full dictionary because I dont know the value of the dictionary.  But no problem. I guess I will filter it in swift then. Thanks for your response

Comment: One way is to create a separate field (type `string`) in your `Device` struct for your `key`‘s only and then if needed, once those are returned, look in your `apps` field for the `value`